# EXT JS Combo drop down not displayed On IE11; EXTJS Popup Window show/display event freezes the application on IE11

Tags: extjs, popup, internet-explorer-11

I am facing following issues for my EXTJS application on IE 11:

1. Combo box drop down not displayed on click of arrow trigger.
2. Application gets freezes when Extjs window show event gets called (application get freezes during display/show event of Extjs popup window).

Application works properly on Chrome/Mozilla.

**Application works properly on *IE-11* which is located at *location A*.**

**Application not responding at all on *IE-11* which is located at *location B*.**

..Girish

Comment: This question is unclear and hard to diagnose without a Fiddle (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor).  Do you think you could create one that shows the issue?

Comment: What is the difference in the settings of IE 11 between location A and location B? Did you get any error where it is not working? Try to reset the IE and again try to check the issue. Try to provide a sample code that can produce the issue with IE 11. We will try to test it to find the cause of the issue.

Comment: Following is the code snippet that I am using to show EXTJS Popup window var selectUsersWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
      title  : 'Select Users',
      autoScroll : true,
      width  : 490,
      height  : 250,
      modal        : true,
      closeAction: 'destroy'      
     });
     selectAddExternalUsersWindow.show();
    }

Comment: Please update your question with a code block instead of posting your code into a comment. Can you reproduce the problem with only this code snippet?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Yes we have tried with reset the internet explorer settings. Following is the code snippet that I am using to show EXTJS Popup window `var selectUsersWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', { title : 'Select Users', autoScroll : true, width : 490, height : 250, modal : true, closeAction: 'destroy' }); selectUsersWindow .show(); } `

Comment: I suggest you create a proper example that we can directly try to run with IE 11 browser. You just posted a JS code that may not help for producing the issue. You can modify the original post with your sample code. We will try to check and test it and provide suggestions.